# Is Laravel 5.1 Compatible with PHP 7

Tags: php, laravel

According to the [installation section](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/installation#installation) on the Laravel website, 5.1 is compatible with PHP >= 5.5.9.

Looking through the [incompatibilities](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php) I can't see anything that immediately flags warning signs.

Has anyone run into issues running PHP 7 with Laravel 5.1?

Edit: [Set Kyar Wa Lar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3736230/set-kyar-wa-lar) linked a useful resource to [PHP 7 and Laravel](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/php-7-and-laravel).

Comment: As for me, it's working well. You can see more discussion on [Laracast Forum](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/php-7-and-laravel)

Comment: I don't know is it because php 7 i m getting tokenmismatch error. Please note its my live site code which is working from last year. Any idea what is the mistake if its not php7

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No issues on my local VM installed from Laravel Homestead Box.
Everything works really fine.

You have all the setup information for this box here and a specific section for PHP 7 upgrade: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead

Answer (score 7):

For [Laravel 5.1.43](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/db580b5), with updated `vendor`, is **compatible with PHP 7**.

and you can make sure through these methods by your self for any version of Laravel.

**1. All unit test passed in PHP 7.0.8**

```
monque@e4300 ~/project/laravel_framework git:(db580b5) ✗ :( $ php phpunit-old.phar
PHPUnit 4.8.27 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:        PHP 7.0.8
Configuration:  /home/monque/project/laravel_framework/phpunit.xml

.............................................................   61 / 1748 (  3%)
.............................................................  122 / 1748 (  6%)
.............................................................  183 / 1748 ( 10%)
.............................................................  244 / 1748 ( 13%)
.............................................................  305 / 1748 ( 17%)
.............................................................  366 / 1748 ( 20%)
.............................................................  427 / 1748 ( 24%)
.............................................................  488 / 1748 ( 27%)
.............................................................  549 / 1748 ( 31%)
.............................................................  610 / 1748 ( 34%)
.............................................................  671 / 1748 ( 38%)
.............................................................  732 / 1748 ( 41%)
.............................................................  793 / 1748 ( 45%)
.............................................................  854 / 1748 ( 48%)
.............................................................  915 / 1748 ( 52%)
.............................................................  976 / 1748 ( 55%)
............................................................. 1037 / 1748 ( 59%)
............................................................. 1098 / 1748 ( 62%)
............................................................. 1159 / 1748 ( 66%)
............................................................. 1220 / 1748 ( 69%)
............................................................. 1281 / 1748 ( 73%)
............................................................. 1342 / 1748 ( 76%)
............................................................. 1403 / 1748 ( 80%)
............................................................. 1464 / 1748 ( 83%)
............................................................. 1525 / 1748 ( 87%)
............................................................. 1586 / 1748 ( 90%)
............................................................. 1647 / 1748 ( 94%)
............................................................. 1708 / 1748 ( 97%)
........................................

Time: 2.55 seconds, Memory: 64.00MB

OK (1748 tests, 3962 assertions)
```

**2. Homestead for 5.1 is already upgrade to PHP 7**

> Homestead runs on any Windows, Mac, or Linux system, and includes the Nginx web server, PHP 7.0, MySQL, Postgres, Redis, Memcached, Node, and all of the other goodies you need to develop amazing Laravel applications.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead

**3. Analysis using [PHP-Migration](https://github.com/monque/PHP-Migration)**

```
monque@e4300 ~/project/laravel_framework git:(db580b5) ✗ $ phpmig -sv70 src   

File: src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Found 1 spot(s), 0 identified
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   35 | WARNING    |   | 7.0.0 | set_exception_handler() is no longer guaranteed to receive Exception objects
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

File: src/Illuminate/Hashing/BcryptHasher.php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Found 1 spot(s), 0 identified
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   30 | DEPRECATED |   | 7.0.0 | salt option for password_hash() is deprecated
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

File: src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Found 1 spot(s), 0 identified
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  157 | NOTICE     |   | 7.0.0 | Modulus operator will throw a exception if divisor is 0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

File: src/Illuminate/Encryption/McryptEncrypter.php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Found 1 spot(s), 0 identified
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  153 | NOTICE     |   | 7.0.0 | Modulus operator will throw a exception if divisor is 0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

These spots is compatible with PHP 7 after manually checking.

Comment: How on earth did you run 1748 in 2.55 seconds? That's insane (and good job!)

Comment: Tried again just now, first time is 18.27 seconds, after first time are 2.87, 2.31, 2.86 seconds. It seems that some data was cached during test.

Answer (score 0):

For better experience with PHP 7.3, you may simply upgrade it to Laravel 5.2.
It works well with PHP 7.3 environment.

Comment: Anything specific on PHP 7.3 that works well with Laravel 5.2 and not 5.1?